Passing a Widget builder function to a RenderObject?
I'm pretty new to Futter here, and I'm trying to build a widget which displays its children widgets horizontally but if some of them overflow, displays an overflow indicator (or overflowWidget) instead.
This should be quite similar to how extended_wrap works, but instead of passing a prebuilt widget as a parameter, I'd like to pass a builder function for the overflowWidget so the widget can hold some useful information such as how many of the children widgets have been clipped off.
An example of how I'm expecting it to work:
The  widget at the end of the row is an example of the overflowWidget built from the builder function passed as a parameter. In this case its signature would be something like Widget Function(int overflowedCount) overflowWidgetBuilder.
So I'd first need to calculate the sizes of each child widget. My current plan is using MultiChildRenderObjectWidget and RenderBox, but inside performLayout(), it looks like I cannot directly build a new widget by calling the builder function.
Is there a workaround for this, or a better idea to realize my idea? Any help would be appreciated.
